# What is the algebra structure on the pushforward of the structure sheaf along a finite map to $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$ Let $f : C \to \P^1$ be a ramified finite map of degree $d$ of smooth algebraic curves over an algebraically closed field $k$. How can we explicitly describe $f_\star \O_C$ as an algebra structure on a sum of line bundles on $\P^1$?

In general we know $f_\star \O_C$ is a coherent sheaf of algebras on $\P^1$ of rank $d$, which by cohomology and base change (or flatness + locally Noetherian) can be seen to be locally free. So its underlying $\O_{\P^1}$-module is a rank $d$ vector bundle. Every vector bundle on $\P^1$ splits as a sum of line bundles $\bigoplus_i \O(n_i)$, and computing the $n_i$ reduces to computing the Hilbert function of $\O_C(f^{-1}([\infty]))$, which requires knowing something about the upstairs geometry.

So $f_{\star} \O_C$ is some algebra structure on vector bundle $\bigoplus_i \O(n_i) $. **Is there a natural geometric way to describe the multiplication across this decomposition?**

#### Example

In the case of an elliptic curve as a double cover of $\P^1$, we have $f_{\star} \O_E \cong \O\oplus \O(-2)$, with the unit corresponding to $1 \in \O$. The top answer on [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44268/how-do-you-describe-vector-bundles-on-elliptic-curves) post claims that the multiplication on the other factor is a map $\O_{\P^1}(-2) \otimes \O_{\P^1}(-2) \cong \O_{\P^1}(-4) \to \O_{\P^1}$ somehow induced by the ramification divisor.

Concretely, maybe, there should be a canonical basis of $H^0(\O(R)) \cong k^4$ corresponding to $x^2, xy, y^2, 1 \in H^0(\O(2) \oplus \O)$, which we can then use to compute a multiplication table on global sections. How do we find this basis?